# Trading strategies - novice mining areas in EVE

Tags: eve-online

I was talking to a corp-mate last night and she mentioned that she used to go to fringe mining systems away from trade hubs and put up buy orders for Trit at much cheaper than the current prices (ie. 1,000,000 trit @ 4.0 ISK ea/ whereas Jita is around 5.07). She said she made a hefty profit because miners either didn't know where to take their minerals or couldn't transport them.

My question is- Can I tell where these systems might be by looking at the starmap and it's associated statistics? Should I use an external website? I have a miner myself, but I normally followed my corp to mine, so I'm not really sure where these systems are I should look for.

Comment: Generally in Eve, if you find something that makes you money; you don't tell anyone else about it (as that adds competition and lowers value). A system where miners unwittingly sell to cheap buy orders would not last long with competition.

Comment: 'hefty profit' is a very loose phrase. In general there isn't that much money to be made moving large amounts of ore/minerals around. There are many ways to get a better profit for time spent

Answer (score 2):

You probably couldn't find these systems from the star map itself. The only real way is to get into a ship and actually go visit some systems a reasonable distance from trade hub.

A site that may give you hints is Eve-Central. Here's a [link](http://eve-central.com/home/quicklook.html?typeid=34) to the Tritanium orders page on it. Look for systems still with green security status, but there are large sell/buy orders for Trit at below Jita prices. Pay careful attention to your route to these systems though, it is possible that the route to some of these places may take you through low-sec where a hauler or freighter may be quite vulnerable to pirates.

Comment: Eve-Central definitely is a good tool for finding trade routes - there actually is a "Trade finder" tool on the website which displays the best trades between two given systems or regions.